# get text content of first HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get just text of html tag Div where `(id = 'div12Item')` that is `(new content )`
below is my html code

```
<div name="div12Item" id="div12Item">

                new content            
              <ul id="sortable" > 

                <li ></span>Item 1</li> 
                <li ></span>Item 2</li> 
                <li ></span>Item 3</li> 

            </ul> 
           </div>
```

when I execute this javascript code         `alert(document.getElementById('div12Item').textContent);`
 I get new content Item 1 Item2 Item3

but me I need just get text in div even if in HTML tag Div there is other HTML tags like my example

Comment: So you *only* want to retrieve the first node, ie `new content`, not any of the text within the child `li` elements - is that right? Also note that your HTML is invalid as you have an odd `</span>` tag in there where it shouldn't be

Comment: yeess Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter out element that have nodetype equal to textnode along with `.text()` to get text of it:

```
var text = $("#div12Item").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).text();
```

```js
var text = $("#div12Item").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).text();
alert(text.trim());
```

```html
   <div name="div12Item" id="div12Item">

            new content            
          <ul id="sortable" > 

            <li ></span>Item 1</li> 
            <li ></span>Item 2</li> 
            <li ></span>Item 3</li> 

        </ul> 
       </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it works perfectlly
can you explain please this line this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
thanks

Comment: @khalil_diouri: we are filtering out the element that have node type as text nodes. here is the doc for nodetype property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only want to retrieve the `new content` value, and that it's always the first child element of `#div12Item`, then you can use the `childNodes` property, like this:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('div12Item').childNodes[0].textContent.trim());
```

```html
<div name="div12Item" id="div12Item">
    new content
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or if you'd prefer to use jQuery, you can use `contents()`:

```js
console.log($('#div12Item').contents().first().text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="div12Item" id="div12Item">
    new content
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("div12Item").childNodes[0].data;

console.log(a); //actual text
console.log(a.replace(/ /g, '')); //whitespaces trimmed
```

```html
<div name="div12Item" id="div12Item">

                new content            
              <ul id="sortable" > 

                <li >Item 1</li> 
                <li >Item 2</li> 
                <li >Item 3</li> 

            </ul> 
           </div>
```

**Hint** 
Always use your browser's javascript console. That way you'll always find new clues. These are steps, how I achieved result. 
**1)**
[image] 
**2)**
[image]
**3)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$("#div12Item").contents().eq(0).text().trim()